# how can i make a vertical carousel slider with multiple items bootstrap and jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Hi guys im trying to make a multiple items or objects carousel slider(vertical), so i tried something like this but my script sucks and wrong obviously and i need some help thnx.

```
<div id="carousel-pager" class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel" data-interval="500000000">
                 <div class="carousel-inner vertical">
    
    
                <div class="active item">
                        <div class="services-2 p-4 d-flex ftco-animate"data-target="#carousel-main" data-slide-to="0">
                            <div class="icon">
                                <span class="flaticon-engineer"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text">
                                <h3>24/7 Help Support</h3>
                                <p>Separated they live in. A small river named Duden flows</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
              </div>
    
              <div class="item">
       <div class="services-2 p-4 d-flex ftco-animate"data-target="#carousel-main" data-slide-to="3">
         <div class="icon">
           <span class="flaticon-engineer-2"></span>
         </div>
         <div class="text">
           <h3>24/7 Help Support</h3>
           <p>Separated they live in. A small river named Duden flows</p>
         </div>
       </div>
    
     </div>
    
     <script>
     $('.carousel .vertical .item').each(function(){
       var next = $(this).next();
       if (!next.length) {
         next = $(this).siblings("div:first");
       }
       next.children("div").clone().appendTo($(this));
    
    
       for (var i=1;i<2;i++) {
         next=next.next();
         if (!next.length) {
           next = $(this).siblings(':first');
         }
    
         next.children().clone().appendTo($(this));
       }
     });
     </script>
```

here some pictures of the final result : [this is start of the slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J92Ni.png) [this is when i start to scroll up or down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1XEu.png)

im using some style

```
    <style>
.carousel-inner.vertical {
  height: 100%; /*Note: set specific height here if not, there will be some issues with IE browser*/
}
.carousel-inner.vertical > .item {
  -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out top;
  -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out top;
  transition: .6s ease-in-out top;
}

@media all and (transform-3d),
(-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-inner.vertical > .item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
  }
  .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.next,
  .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.active.right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 33.33%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 33.33%, 0);
    top: 0;
  }
  .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.prev,
  .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.active.left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -33.33%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -33.33%, 0);
    top: 0;
  }
  .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.next.left,
  .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.prev.right,
  .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    top: 0;
  }
}

.carousel-inner.vertical > .active {
  top: 0;
}
.carousel-inner.vertical > .next,
.carousel-inner.vertical > .prev {
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.carousel-inner.vertical > .next {
  left: 0;
  top: 33.33%;
  right:0;
}
.carousel-inner.vertical > .prev {
  left: 0;
  top: -33.33%;
  right:0;
}
.carousel-inner.vertical > .next.left,
.carousel-inner.vertical > .prev.right {
  top: 0;
}
.carousel-inner.vertical > .active.left {
  left: 0;
  top: -33.33%;
  right:0;
}
.carousel-inner.vertical > .active.right {
  left: 0;
  top: 33.33%;
  right:0;
}

#carousel-pager .carousel-control.left {
    bottom: initial;
    width: 100%;
}
#carousel-pager .carousel-control.right {
    top: initial;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Without the CSS it's rather hard to see what is going on. Are you using some plugin/library for the carousel? Could you post a working snippet?

Comment: Says in the title that he is using bootstrap, a precision on which version would be helpful.

Comment: You can try something like [this](https://www.codeply.com/go/PgxKT3h6x6/bootstrap-4-vertical-slider)

Comment: hi  @A Haworth yes im using some style and i just update the post + those are the library s   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
and other jquery and bootstrap librarys

Comment: @yi fan im tried this https://codepen.io/BloodyBride/pen/ERLRrB  but its scrolle one item in my case i want to start scrolling from the third item, i need three active items like in the first pic